# docx4j create numbered and unnumbered list

Tags: java, ms-word, docx4j

I need to create a document that contains numbered as well as unnumbered lists using docx4j.
I know that there are codes for numbered and unnumbered lists but I can't get it together.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below step:

1. Create a numbering definition and add it to Main document part.

   `NumberingDefinitionsPart ndp = new NumberingDefinitionsPart();
    ndp.setJaxbElement(ndp.unmarshalDefaultNumbering());
    mdp.addTargetPart(ndp);`
2. Use NumId 1, if you want to create Oredered list and 2, if you want to create Unordered list.
3. If you want to restart numbering, use restart method.

a. For Ordered list,

```
long newNumId = 1;
newNumId = ndp.restart(newNumId, 0, 1);
```

b. For Unordered list,

```
long newNumId = 2;
newNumId = ndp.restart(newNumId, 0, 1);
```